# A multiple choice question concerning first order linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the initial value problem $$y'(t)=f(t)y(t)$$ with $y(0)=1$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a  continuous function.

Then this initial value problem has

(1) Infinitely many solutions for some $f$

(2)a unique solution in $\mathbb{R}$

(3) no solution in $\mathbb{R}$ for some $f$

(4) a solution in an interval containing $0$, but not on $\mathbb{R}$ for some $f$

**My efforts**

$$\frac{dy(t)}{y(t)} = f(t)dt$$

$$\log y(t) = \int_0^tf(t)dt +C$$

Now at $t=0$ $y=1$ so we get

$$0=0+C$$

So $$y(t)=\exp(\int_0^tf(t)dt)$$

**So either $2$ is true or $4$ is true? I am not able to go further from here. What logic should I use now**

Edit:

Since $\int_{0}^{t} f$ is continuous and $e^x$ is continuous and composition of continuous function is continuous so $2$ is true. Is this a correct way of thinking?

Comment: Kind of an unusual multiple choice question when the choices are far from being mutually exclusive :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the correct choice is ***(2)*** and only ***(2)***.

I reason as follows:

For $f(t) \in C(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)$, consider the function

$F_f: \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R, \; F_f(y, t) = yf(t); \tag 1$

then $F_f(y, t)$ is ***(a.)*** jointly continuous in $y$ and $t$, and ***(b.)*** (locally in $t$) Lipschitz continuous in $y$.

To see ***(a.)***, note that $F_f(y, t) = yf(t)$ is the product of the two continuous functions $y: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, and that multiplication is itself continuous from $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.

As for ***(b.)***, we have, for $y, z, t \in \Bbb R$,

$\vert F(z, t) - F(y, t) \vert = \vert zf(t) - yf(t) \vert = \vert(z - y)f(t) \vert = \vert z - y \vert \vert f(t) \vert; \tag 2$

now since $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, in any closed interval $I_{t_0}$ about any $t_0 \in \Bbb R$, $f(t)$ is bounded there; thus, there is a neighborhood $J_{t_0} \subset I_{t_0}$ of $t_0$ and a constant $L_J > 0$ such that

$\vert f(t) \vert < L_J, \; t \in J_{t_0}; \tag 3$

thus for $z, y \in \Bbb R$ and $t \in J$ we have

$\vert F(z, t) - F(y, t) \vert < L_J \vert z - y \vert, \tag 4$

which shows that $F(y, t)$ is Lipschitz continuous on some interval $J_{t_0}$ containing $t_0$; thus, by the [Picard-Lindeloef theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) the exists a *unique* solution to our differential equation

$\dot y = F(y, t) = f(t)y, \; y(t_0) = y_0, \tag 5$

on some interval $(t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon)$ containing $t_0$; furthermore, since this is true for any $t_0$, such integral curves may be maximally extended to all of $\Bbb R$ and thus we see there exists a *unique, global solution* passing through any $(y_0, t_0) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$; since this is true for any $f(t) \in C(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)$, we may rule out possibilities ***(1)*** and ***(3)*** in our OP Stammering Mathematician's list.  Similarly, we may eliminate item ***(4)*** from consideration since, as we have seen, there is a solution for *every* $f$ in an interval about *any* $t_0$, $t_0 = 0$ included.

So, ***(2)*** is true and only ***(2)*** is true.

The particularly simple form of $F(y, t) = f(t)y$ in fact makes it possible to verify the above results in an immediate, practical way without resorting to the theoretial arguments presented above; indeed, if

$y(t_0) = y_0 \ne 0 \tag 6$

for *some* $t_0 \in \Bbb R$, then in a neighborhood of $t_0$ we have

$\dfrac{\dot y(t)}{y(t)} = f(t), \tag 7$

whence

$\dfrac{d\ln y(t)}{dt} = f(t), \tag 8$

so that

$\ln \left (\dfrac{y(t)}{y(t_0)} \right ) = \ln y(t) - \ln y(t_0) = \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t \dfrac{d\ln y(s)}{ds} \; ds = \int_{t_0}^t f(s) \; ds, \tag 9$

and so

$y(t) = y(t_0) \exp \left (\displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t f(s) \; ds \right ). \tag{10}$

The solution (10) is easily seen to be valid, unique, and to extend to all $\Bbb R$, and binds as long as $y(t_0) \ne 0$ for *some* $t_0 \in \Bbb R$; the only other alternative is $y(t) = 0$ *everywhere*, which is also seen to be a unique global solution.

Finally, if we choose with our OP

$y(0) = 1, \tag{11}$

we find the unique global solution to be

$y(t) = \exp \left ( \displaystyle \int_0^t f(s) \; ds \right ), \tag{12}$

in accord with our previous calculations.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. This is great explanation!!! Now I understand what is going on in the backdrop.. Thanks again for taking time to write such a long and detailed answer.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician:  my pleasure, my friend.  Thanks for the kind words, and the "acceptance".  Cheers!

Comment: How does the Picard-Lindeloef theorem show the solution can be extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$? Perhaps the $\epsilon$ in your proof gets smaller as $t_0\to T$.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Since the integral, $\int _0^t f(t)dt $ exists for all t, you have a solution for all t.